# Why does adding script.js file into /var/www/html/ into my EC2 server crash the server?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

So I have been trying to add script.js into my /var/www/html/ directory in a UBUNTU EC2 AWS Instance using VS Code Remote SSH extension. The directory has 777 permission yet when I save my file, the server stops responding and I can not connect to it through VS Code, terminal, nor the AWS CloudShell. I also can not access the public DNS to see my website anymore either.

I have the port 22 on 0.0.0.0 and all security groups correctly configured. The status checks all come back 2/2. I also have LAMP stack installed. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I suggest taking a look at the http logs.  As you haven't provided what script.js contains, it's difficult to determine why it would cause the server to 'crash'.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?